Error in reasoning for electric field outside a cylinder
Suppose we have a cylinder of length $L$ with uniform charge density that has its central axis on the $z$ axis and the center of its bottom face located at the origin. Let $P_z$ be any point that lies outside the cylinder at a height of $ 0 < z < L.$
Apparently, the one and only direction the electric field at $P_z$ points in is radially outward from the cylinder. But it does not make sense to me why this is the case, as my own reasoning about the problem contradicts this. So I would like help in finding the flaw in my reasoning.
My reasoning is this: I can see why $\mathbf{E}_{\theta}$ due to the cylinder at $P_z$ is $0$ but I cannot see why $\mathbf{E}_z$ is $0.$ for all $P_z$. In particular, if $P_z$ lies at a height above or below the middle of the cylinder, say at height $\frac{3}{4}L$, then I don’t see how $\mathbf{E}_z$ could be zero at $P_z$. Because if you imagine a plane containing $P_z$ and intersecting a horizontal cross section of the cylinder, then $\mathbf{E}_z$ due to any point $A$ in the cylinder above the plane is going to cancel out with $\mathbf{E}_z$ due to the point in the cylinder that is symmetric with $A$ across the plane, and vice versa. And $\mathbf{E}_z$ due to any point on the plane is $0$ since the $z$-component of the separation vector is $0.$ Thus the net magnitude of $\mathbf{E}_z$ due to the top half of the cylinder is $0$; but the net magnitude of $\mathbf{E}_z$ due to the bottom half of the cylinder will be nonzero, because there is no symmetry about $P_z$ for the contribution of the points below $\frac{1}{2}L$ (in the $z$-direction) to cancel out like the points above $\frac{1}{2}L$ did.
Using similar reasoning it would seem $\mathbf{E}_z$ at points above $L$ or below $0$ should also be nonzero, which again is apparently not the correct conclusion.
So what am I doing wrong here? Is there some other source of symmetry that causes cancellation which I am just not seeing?

Why do you assume that the electric field for a finite cylinder is radially outward? That is only true for the infinitely long case, as far as I know.

Your argument is correct. The reflection symmetry that guarantees $E_z=0$ for an infinite cylinder does not apply for a finite cylinder (except for the horizontal plane that intersects the cylinder halfway up its height), and so there is no reason for $E_z$ to be zero, and in fact it isn't zero.

@PatoGalmarini it appears I misread a problem in my textbook.

RE: "Apparently, the one and only direction the electric field at $P_z$ points in is radially outward from the cylinder", this is an incorrect premise. What made you believe it was true?

@ThePhoton as I said above, I misread a problem in my textbook
